# Use array as string and remove double quotes symbol to change array content type from string to any, as whole array will be string its type can be any

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uikit

I been stuck at this for far too long. I have to send this array as string: `"[{\"packageId\":\"1\"}, {\"packageId\":\"1\"}, {\"packageId\":\"3\"}]"` and so on. The values here are being inserted and can be any integer.
As I cannot declare any variable in format like `let pjson = {\"packageId\":\"1\"}` so I decided to create a string instead in this way: `let pjson = "{\"packageId\":\"1\"}"` and using for loop im adding data in some array in following way:

```
for package in packages {
       if let pId = package.packageId {
            let pjson = "{\"packageId\":\"\(pId)\"}"
             packageJson.append(pjson as Any)
        }
 }
```

After this im getting an array like this:

```
packageJson = ["{\"packageId\":\"1\"}", "{\"packageId\":\"2\"}", "{\"packageId\":\"3\"}", "{\"packageId\":\"4\"}", "{\"packageId\":\"5\"}", "{\"packageId\":\"6\"}"]
```

Now I want to convert my `packageJson` to this format:

```
packageJson = [{\"packageId\":\"1\"}, {\"packageId\":\"2\"}, {\"packageId\":\"3\"}, {\"packageId\":\"4\"}, {\"packageId\":\"5\"}, {\"packageId\":\"6\"}]
```

As you can see, I don't want array content to be a string type.

So I stored whole array as string and decided to remove those  `"` like this:

```
var stringJson = "\(packageJson)"
stringJson = stringJson.replacingOccurrences(of: "\\{", with: "{", options: NSString.CompareOptions.literal, range: nil)
stringJson = stringJson.replacingOccurrences(of: "}\\", with: "}", options: NSString.CompareOptions.literal, range: nil)
```

I tried to `""{"` but got error so using `"\\{"` as I read somewhere it can be used for `"` however that answer wasn't market correct so not sure.

How can I remove those `"` to convert array into my required format? Or is there any better way to declare `let pjson = "{\"packageId\":\"\(pId)\"}"` so I can simply add that without having to use string format? Swift doesn't allow to start a variable with "{" tho.

Anyway I would just like to get final result in this way:

```
stringJson = "[{\"packageId\":\"1\"}, {\"packageId\":\"2\"}, {\"packageId\":\"3\"}, {\"packageId\":\"4\"}, {\"packageId\":\"5\"}, {\"packageId\":\"6\"}]"
```

Comment: Ever heard of `Encodable`?

Comment: What type of array is the `packages` that you are looping over? It seems like you can just conform that type to `Encodable` and encode it with a `JSONEncoder`.

Comment: The accepted answer from Dark Zhao (while functional) is a very bad idea. You should not be writing JSON strings by hand like this. The answer from burnsi is much better and will help you immensely in the future. Please follow that one instead

Comment: @SimonMcLoughlin I tested both and both worked but I happened to implement that answer first so I accepted that. Thanks for the info. For future users your comment will help to choose better approach. I have kept other answer as useful answer and accepted answer mentioned by you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your final result is a JSON string of an array of custom objects. There is a way more simpler way to achieve what you want.

First create a struct to hold your values:

```
struct PackageContainer: Codable{
    var packageId: String
}
```

Then create you data as you deem fit. Example:

```
let packages = (0...10).map{ PackageContainer(packageId: "\($0)") }
```

Then encode them with JSONEncoder:

```
let json = try JSONEncoder().encode(packages)
```

This will give you a `Data` object. You can treat it as string if you like or send it in the body of a datarequest.

---

Example:

```
print(String(data: json, encoding: .utf8)!)
```

will produce:

> [{"packageId":"0"},{"packageId":"1"},{"packageId":"2"},{"packageId":"3"},{"packageId":"4"},{"packageId":"5"},{"packageId":"6"},{"packageId":"7"},{"packageId":"8"},{"packageId":"9"},{"packageId":"10"}]

Answer (score 1):

In Swift 5.0+

```
let ids = [1, 2]

let idsString = ids.map { id -> String in
    return "{\"packageId\"" + ":" + "\"\(id)\"}"
}.joined(separator: ",")

let result = "[" + idsString + "]"
print(result)
```

you will get the results:

`[{"packageId":"1"},{"packageId":"2"}]`